# Stored procedure is not returning data

Tags: php, sql-server, linux

I am in the progress of transferring a script from a (discontinued) windows server to our Linux one. One of the scripts I need to transfer is a connection with a `MSSQL`-server.

The connection with the server is established and I am able to fetch "regular" data from any of the tables, but when I execute a stored procedure, I don't receive any of the desired data. The procedure just returns `false` when executed.

Testing the prepared statement for errors with `$stmt->errorInfo()` does not show me any relevant information, it just returns error code `00000`, which should indicate everything (should) work fine.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => 0
    [2] => (null) [0] (severity 0) [(null)]
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
)
```

---

*php*

```
$con = new \PDO('dblib:charset=UTF-8;host=freedts;dbname=database', 'user', 'password');
/** ------------------------------------------------------**/
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM prgroepen';
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
if ($stmt) {
    try {
        $stmt->execute();
        $data = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($data) echo '<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre>';
        else var_dump($data);

    }catch(\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

/** ------------------------------------------------------**/
$SP = <<<SQL
    DECLARE @return_value int,
            @soort nvarchar(1),
            @dagen money

    EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[web_voorraadstatus] @produkt = N'ABEC24_9002', @aantal = 1, @soort = @soort OUTPUT, @dagen = @dagen OUTPUT
    SELECT  @soort as N'@soort', @dagen as N'@dagen'
SQL;

$stmt = $con->prepare($SP);
if ($stmt) {
    try {
        $stmt->execute();
        $data = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($data) echo '<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre>';
        else var_dump($data);

    }catch(\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

---

*output*

```
Array
(
    [kode] => A
    [omschrijving] => ACCESSOIRE DISPLAYS
    [aeenheid] => ST
    [agb] => 604006
    [veenheid] => ST
    [vgb] => 700011
    [coefaank] => 
    [coefverk] => 
    [internet] => 1
    [foto] => #\\serverpc\fws$\GROEPEN\A.jpg#
    [vader] => 
    [produkt_niveau] => 0
    [bs_kode] => 
    [bs_vader] => 
    [web_volgorde] => 6
    [pdfcataloog] => 
)

bool(false)
```

---

I also tried to call the SP in different ways, but with no avail as well.
The exact same code runs perfectly on the windows server, with the only difference is that the windows server uses the `sqlsrv`-driver

```
/** ============================== **/
/*  @produkt as nvarchar(15),
/*  @aantal as money,
/*  @soort as nvarchar(1) output,
/*  @dagen as money output
/** ============================== **/
$stmt = $con->prepare('execute web_voorraadstatus ?, ?, ?, ?');

$stmt->bindParam(1, $produkt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $aantal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $soort, PDO::PARAM_STR, 1);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $dagen, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);

var_dump($stmt->execute()); # true
var_dump($soort, $dagen);   # NULL, NULL
```

---

So is `dblib` actually able to execute stored procedures *and* retrieving the data returned by it?

*note: the client charset is already set to `UTF-8` in the `FreeDTS` config file*

---

Here is a partial from the `freeDTS` log, it's seems I'm receiving data from the `MSSQL`-server just fine?

```
dblib.c:4639:dbsqlok(0x7fcfd8acc530)
dblib.c:4669:dbsqlok() not done, calling tds_process_tokens()
token.c:540:tds_process_tokens(0x7fcfd78d7bd0, 0x7ffe281bec38, 0x7ffe281bec3c, 0x6914)
util.c:156:Changed query state from PENDING to READING
net.c:555:Received header
0000 04 01 00 5c 00 37 01 00-                        |...\.7..|

net.c:609:Received packet
0000 04 01 00 5c 00 37 01 00-79 00 00 00 00 fe 01 00 |...\.7.. y.......|
0010 e0 00 00 00 00 00 81 02-00 00 00 21 00 e7 02 00 |........ ...!....|
0020 09 04 d0 00 34 06 40 00-73 00 6f 00 6f 00 72 00 |....4.@. s.o.o.r.|
0030 74 00 00 00 21 00 6e 08-06 40 00 64 00 61 00 67 |t...!.n. .@.d.a.g|
0040 00 65 00 6e 00 d1 02 00-56 00 08 00 00 00 00 90 |.e.n.... V.......|
0050 d0 03 00 fd 10 00 c1 00-01 00 00 00             |........ ....|
```

Comment: I had some problems with FreeTDS and dblib before. Try enabling the freetds log to get more information... I ended up using the [msphpsql extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql)

Comment: Can you show your stored procedure code. `SET NOCOUNT ON` is used?

Comment: @DiogoSgrillo The log is not showing much, also i'm stuck with `PHP5.4` at this point so that library is not for me i'm afrai

Comment: @gofr1 Even with `SET NOCOUNT ON` i'm getting `false` as return

Comment: @DarkBee but the result set is returned on the log? Try using the `tsql` for executing the procedure, then you make sure if the problem is on odbc + freetds or dblib+php

Comment: It seems that [FreeTDS can't handle output parameters in MSSQL Server 7 SP3 or greater](http://www.freetds.org/faq.html#ms.output.parameters)

Comment: @DiogoSgrillo I've added an extract of the log

Comment: @DiogoSgrillo Well add that an answer I guess. To bad the reference to `dbrpcparam` is dead in the `FAQ` section

Comment: Before giving up, try passing (in your second example) the `PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT` while binding the parameters to your procedure: `$stmt->bindParam(3, $soort, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 1);`

Comment: Nope, i did give that a try as well but unfortunately no result(s). Seems I will need to stick with running this codebase on a windows server

Comment: Can you print  print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true); it will show error.

Comment: I'm not using the `sqlserv` drivers, as these are the Windows drivers and i'm trying to get this work on Linux, but I added the relevant error information

Comment: Why you don’t do fetch after the execute method in the same way as your first example?

Comment: I did that. Watch the examples I posted, one is a simple select which is working just fine. The stored procedure is not returning the result set even when I used `fetch` (thats `var_dump` which outputs false)

Comment: If only I could remember what it was about - I had a similar issue with calling stored procedures on MSSQL server with PHP, and it was connected with dblib... I thought we had it changed to another driver..

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but I think this is the standard behavior of DBLIB and FreeTDS, in that they have a one statement per connection rule.

To workaround open connection object for each statement - making sure you close the cursor after each fetch.

```
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

sqlsrv on Windows does not have this behaviour hence the different results across platforms.

Comment: Even when executing just one prepared statement. It still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

If you are hemmed in by the version of PHP and FreeTDS, a sort of kludge might serve depending on your performance requirements.

In broad strokes;

1. Create a view based on your stored procedure
2. query the view
3. drop the view

A few different approaches are discussed on this MSDN thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/75a686f0-2192-4c6c-bdb8-04c074b916fc/create-view-from-stored-procedure?forum=transactsql

Notably:

```
declare @sql_String nvarchar(4000)
set @sql_String = N'
create view dbo.Whatever as
select ''Hello World'' as Hello_World'

exec sp_executeSql @sql_String
```

Answer (score 0):

- Try to run SQL Profiler at SQL Server and see what is running and if it is generating any warnings / errors.
- Could you try to execute your SP as below?

  SELECT CAST(soort AS NVARCHAR(1)) as N'@soort', CAST(dagen AS MONEY) as N'@dagen'

  FROM OPENQUERY([server_name],

  'DECLARE @return_value int, @soort nvarchar(1), @dagen money

  EXEC @return_value = db_name.[dbo].[web_voorraadstatus] @produkt = N''ABEC24_9002'', @aantal = 1, @soort = @soort OUTPUT, @dagen = @dagen OUTPUT

  SELECT @soort as N''soort'', @dagen as N''dagen''

  ')

server_name is what is shown in

```
select name
from sys.servers
where server_id = 0
```