# twig how to render a twig template as a variable

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to render twig template as variable, using symfony. I have a 'sendAction' Controller, which uses the mailgun API to send emails to one or more mailing lists. Here is my code for the Controller:

```
public function sendAction(Request $request, Newsletter $newsletter, MailgunManager $mailgunManager) {
  $form = $this->createForm(SendForm::class);
  $form->handleRequest($request);

  $formData = array();

  if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $formData = $form->getData();

        $mailingLists = $formData['mailingLists'];

        foreach ($mailingLists as $list) {

            $mailgunManager->sendMail($list->getAddress(), $newsletter->getSubject(), 'test', $newsletter->getHtmlContent());

            return $this->render('webapp/newsletter/sent.html.twig');
        }
    }
    return $this->render('webapp/newsletter/send.html.twig', array(
        'newsletter' => $newsletter,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
  }
}
```

And here's my sendMail (mailgun) function:

```
  public function sendMail($mailingList, $subject, $textBody, $htmlBody) {

   $mgClient = new Mailgun($this::APIKEY);

   # Make the call to the client.
         $mgClient->sendMessage($this::DOMAIN, array(
            'from'      => $this::SENDER,
            'to'        => $mailingList,
            'subject'   => $subject,
            'text'      => $textBody,
            'html'      => $htmlBody
        ));
  }
```

I want my ' $newsletter->getHtmlContent()' to render template called 'newsletter.twig.html'. can anyone help me or point me in the right direction as to what I can do or Where I can find Tutorials or notes on what I am trying to do. the symfony documentation is quite vague.

Comment: You want to render the template `newsletter.twig.html` inside the template `webapp/newsletter/send.html.twig` ?

Comment: You should just do something like e.g. `$mailgunManager->sendMail($list->getAddress(), $newsletter->getSubject(), 'test', $this->render($newsletter->getTemplate()));`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, in case an answer helps you, you can mark it as correct by clicking the tickmark on the left of the answer.

Comment: @DarkBee: Why do you keep removing the `php` and `twig` tags? Don’t you think that the question is related to PHP or Twig?

Comment: @lxg I don't think so no. There is not a letter `twig` in here and it aint a `php` problem on itself.

Comment: Uh, but it’s about rendering a Twig template and accessing the rendering engine. And of course, it’s a PHP question. Look at pretty much all language-related questions, pretty much all of them deal with a particular technology implemented in the given language. I think you are a bit overzealous with tag editing. By the way, (mere) tag edits don’t add to your edit count, so they won’t help you getting the remaining 3 points for your „Copy Editor“ badge. ;)

Comment: @Lxg I'm not here the badge.. For what it's worth (and then I shut up) OP even could try to render a smarty template. I just try to keep tags at their minimum and best purpose. I mean someone could click the `twig`-tag for this question and not be able to solve it because it focuses on how to pass/access an instance of a service inside a controller.

Comment: Maybe so, but that’s true for many questions, and I don’t think too many people are bothered by this. By the way, you could start fixing tags on your own questions, e.g. why does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49231031/stored-procedure-is-not-returning-data question carry the `linux` tag? Also, why don’t you use the `freedts` on your questions regarding to the FreeDTS lib? Another post carries the `php` tag, but also isn’t “a php problem on itself”. You’re being inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getContent()` chained to your render function.

```
return $this->render('webapp/newsletter/send.html.twig', array(
        'newsletter' => $newsletter,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ))->getContent();
```

Comment: So you’re creating a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` object, just to get the rendered content? Nice hack. ;)

Comment: No I didn’t. The `getContent()` method is on the `Response` object returned by `$this->render()`. You’re effectively returning the response body.

Comment: Yeah, didn't notice that initially, my bad :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply inject an instance of `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface` into your action, and you’ll be able to use Twig directly:

```
public function sendAction(Request $request, EngineInterface $tplEngine, Newsletter $newsletter, MailgunManager $mailgunManager)
{
    // ... other code
    $html = $tplEngine->render('webapp/newsletter/send.html.twig', [
        'newsletter' => $newsletter,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Note that `$this->render()` (in the controller action) will return an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response`, while `$tplEngine->render()` returns a HTML string.

Comment: The thing is also need the subject and the text body to be injected into the template, as I have placeholders for those variables in the template.

Comment: Basically, I don"t the subscriber to just receive the email as just the html content, but receive it as the a template with all the other variables injected into the template.

Comment: You can simply pass additional values into the array which is the second parameter to the `render` method. They will be available as Twig variables by the name of the array key.